# using array collection to populate the Tree in Flex

Tags: flex4, flash-builder, arraycollection

I created an Array Collection that has two layer objects like below, but I get just one layer result. I just see "Countries" result on tree. I set labelField as 'Name' 
. So what could be my mistake?

> Countries ---- Turkey
>         -
>         ---- England
>         -
>         ---- USA

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by using GroupCollection2 . You may use following link http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/GroupingCollection2.html